# Why assigning a session variable isn't working? Node.js

Tags: node.js, session

Im trying to build a simple login system but when i try the asign the session i get this error

> Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

However this is my code:

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'keyboard cat',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,}))
```

This is the login controller:

```
    const loginModel = require('../model/loginModel');
    module.exports = {
    login : async function(req,res){
        try {
        const query = await loginModel.login(req.body.email,req.body.password);
        if(query != null){
            req.session.user = query;
            res.status(200).json(req.session.user);
        }else{
            res.status(401).json({error : true});
        }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send('something went wrong');
        }
        
    }
}
```

NOTE : login model is 100% working and its retrieving the user from database

Comment: Are you running the `express-session` middleware before this request?  That is required to create the `req.session` object and to tie it to a cookie.

Comment: you mean running the first code ? yes im running the first code with nodemon

Comment: Well, something is not working properly with the session middleware because `req.session` does not appear to exist based on the error you are getting.  Are the routes declared in the right order (with the session middleware first).  Perhaps you should show us much more of your code so we can see where these two things fit relative to one another.  It's also possible that you're passing the wrong arguments to the `login()` function.  We can't see what the problem is without seeing more code.

Comment: okay i'll add more core

Comment: i found the error i called the middleware in the wrong file xD i should called it in index.js .Thank you my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something is not working properly with the session middleware because `req.session` does not appear to exist based on the error you are getting. Here are some of the things it could be:

1. Your session middleware is not getting properly run.
2. Your session middleware is running AFTER the route in which you're trying to use `req.session`.  It must be run BEFORE because that middleware is what creates the `req.session` object and loads its data based on the session cookie.
3. Based on this code, you could also get this error if you were passing the wrong `req` argument to your `login(req, res)` method so it's worth checking that too.

We can't see specifically what the problem is without seeing more code.

Comment: session middleware wasn't running properly .